# Binomial congruence modulo prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Let $a$, $b$ $(b≤a)$ be two positive integers are not twin primes and $p$ is any prime number.

Is this congruence

$$ \binom{a^p}{b^p}  \equiv  \binom{a}{b}^p \pmod{p} $$

valid?

Comment: @MarkWildon how do you apply Lucas?

Comment: I've deleted an inaccurate comment saying it followed from Lucas' Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, you may take $a=3$,$b=2$,$p=2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is equivalent to 3 mod 4 then $a\choose 2$ is odd and $a^2\choose 4$ is even. So the proposed congruence fails with $b=2$, $p=2$ and any such $a$.